# SQL Server 2008 VarChar(Max) returns only 8000 Characters. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar, varcharmax

```
PRINT Convert(VarChar(Max),Replicate('1234567890 ',1000))
```

This returns to the window 7,997 characters.

```
SELECT Convert(VarChar(Max),Replicate('1234567890 ',1000))
```

This returns to the grid 7,996 characters. The extra character in the print window is a CRLF. I have my options as such:
Tools → Options → Query Results → Results to Text → Maximum number of characters displayed in each column = 8192

So, I would expect 8,192 characters to be returned in the grid, and I would expect 11,001 characters to be returned to my window.

Then there's this test:

```
DECLARE @VarCharMax VarChar(Max)
SET @VarCharMax = Replicate('123456',2000)
SELECT Right(@VarCharMax,3) -- returns 456
SELECT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,8000),3) -- returns 456
SELECT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,7999),3) -- returns 456
SELECT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,7998),3) -- returns 456
SELECT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,7997),3) -- returns 345
SELECT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,7996),3) -- returns 234
```

What am I missing in understanding here? It doesn't seem to behave at all as I would expect?

Answer (score 4):

8000 characters is a limitation of the replicate function unless the argument is of type varchar(max)/nvarchar(max)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx

> If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), REPLICATE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be explicitly cast to the appropriate large-value data type.

Comment: By default it truncates to 8K, but you can cast the results larger. i.e. using varchar(max) as OP did

Comment: The cast is not to the result but to the argument

Comment: Actually before I saw it

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT len(Replicate(cast('1234567890' as varchar(max)),1000))

Returns 10000
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some explanation.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Dudu's initial answer was simply "8000 characters is a limitation of the replicate function".  I was illustrating that there is an easy work around.

Answer (score 1):

your '123456' text inside the replicate function is not varchar(max) data type. As Dudu mentioned replicate function as limitation for 8000 chars if expression is not varchar(max) data type.

Answer (score 0):

Dudu explained it clearly. Below string is 9,060 characters.

```
 DECLARE @VarCharMax VarChar(Max)
 SET @VarCharMax = 'This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!'
 PRINT Right(@VarCharMax,3)  -- returns st!
 PRINT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,8000),3) -- returns is 
 PRINT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,7999),3) -- returns his
 PRINT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,7998),3) -- returns Thi
 PRINT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,7997),3) -- returns !Th
 PRINT Right(Left(@VarCharMax,7996),3) -- returns t!h
```

This returns as I would expect.

Comment: OK, ... this kind of works?!?! It properly evaluates it in memory, but the actual print statement and the return to the grid is still limited to 7,997 characters. I digress to not close this question, as I don't see that it has been answered yet.

Comment: *Results to Grid* and *Results to Text* are limited by the options you highlighted, in the OP.  Non-XML cells have an upper cap of [65,535 characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190078.aspx).  [Print](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is limited to 8,000 characters.  As far as I can tell; this is a hard limit, without workaround.